Could not find http-builder-0.7.2.jar (org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2)
Use the below lib. inside the project. ( add using jar file )
https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid
in this " classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:2.0.1'" this classpath not find. change using the "   classpath 'gradle.plugin.org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:3.0.0'" this path and working. After the below error are coming.

Could not find http-builder-0.7.2.jar (org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.7.2/http-builder-0.7.2.jar

Cannot find suggestion. Pls share the your suggestion and help about this issue.
i  try many codes but not succussed

As pointed by maven at
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.7.2
I could solve this issue by adding
buildscript {
    repositories {
      maven { url 'https://nexus.web.cern.ch/nexus/content/repositories/public/' }
      ...rest
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
      maven { url 'https://nexus.web.cern.ch/nexus/content/repositories/public/' }
      ...rest

    }
}


i spent 4 days to solve this issue with your solution. Big thank @javier Cuervvas
