Unable to Build the project
Unable to build the project, working fine in my teammate laptop cross checked with all the configuration but none of them worked help me stuck from 2 months
A problem occurred configuring root project

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2.
Required by:
project : > com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3
Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2.

help me fix this issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79073916/could-not-find-http-builder-0-7-2-jar-org-codehaus-groovy-modules-http-builder  Maybe your teammate already had the artefact in the gradle cache on their computer.

Turn off Gradle offline and sync project. You may need a VPN if you have limited access to the project repositories.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio
